# Is other a way to extract unique values in excel without using array formula?

Tags: excel

I used this formula - =IFERROR(INDEX('Master 2'!$G$3:$G$80000,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(working!$D$2:D2,'Master 2'!$G$3:$G$80000),0)),"")

but it made my excel file very slow. It take some 45 - 60 mins to get the result.

Comment: If you can use VBA then it will be faster. Are you looking for formulas only?

Comment: Upgrade your Excel version to the latest one and you get the UNIQUE function.